# How to set IONIC4 set tabs background transparent?

Tags: ionic-framework, styles, ionic4

I use ionic4 now. And my client and his designer give a picture like below.

[image]

It need to make tabs has transparent but I don't know how to set. I have try to add in `variables.scss` but the transparent is no working. If only change color is work.

```
.ion-color-tabstrans {
  --ion-color-base: rgba(100,100,100,0.1);;
}
```

Comment: desginer picture: http://applinkupload.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/alucard263096/banlanmall/inst/191eb281f4e9be860221d61ff2ea1654_19051622002.jpg

Answer (score 9):

From the **[`tab-bar`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tab-bar)** docs seems like you can change the background by using the `--background` CSS property like this:

**HTML**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <!-- Tab bar -->
  <ion-tab-bar class="my-custom-tab-bar" slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="account">
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="contact">
      <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
      <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

**SCSS**

```
ion-tab-bar.my-custom-tab-bar {
  --background: rgba(100,100,100,0.1);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You'd probably need to change the background of the **[ion-tab-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tab-button)** as well

```
ion-tab-bar.my-custom-tab-bar ion-tab-button {
  --background: transparent;
}
```

---

**EDIT II**

The answer above is correct, but is missing something that makes everything not to work as expected. The problem is that the `ion-tabs` element is placed **outside** of the element that represents the content. What you need based on your question is to place the tabs **above** the content instead.

One way to do that is by setting the positioning of the `ion-tabs` to be absolute, like this:

**HTML**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <!-- I've added a my-custom-tab-bar class to the ion-tab-bar element -->
  <ion-tab-bar class="my-custom-tab-bar">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

**SCSS**

```
ion-tab-bar.my-custom-tab-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  --background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);

  ion-tab-button {
    --background: transparent;
  }
}
```

That produces this result:

[image: tabs]

**Notes**

1. Please notice that since the tabs are above the content, you will need to add some `margin-bottom` to the content of each page that is used as a tab.
2. Also please double check if setting the positioning of the tabs to be absolute doesn't break the layout specially in devices with a `safe-area` at the bottom like the iPhone X.

Comment: Could you send me the demo?

Comment: @alucard263096 I've updated my answer, please take a look at it when you have time :)